# How to to mount other drives in FreeDOS

Tags: freedos

How can I mount in FreeDOS, if mounting other drives is even possible? If it is which types of media can be mounted and which ones can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What file systems are supported?

> FAT32 is fully supported and is the preferred format for the boot
>   drive.
>
> Depending on the BIOS used, up to four LBA (Logical block addressing)
>   hard disks up to 128 GB, or 2 TB, in size are supported.[38] There has
>   been little testing with large disks, and some BIOSes support LBA but
>   produce errors on disks larger than 32 GB; a driver such as OnTrack or
>   EZ-Drive resolves this problem.
>
> FreeDOS can also be used with a driver named LFNDOS to enable support
>   for Windows 95-style long file names, but most old programs before
>   Win95 do not support LFNs even with driver loaded unless they have
>   been recompiled.
>
> There is no planned support for NTFS, ext2 or exFAT, but there are
>   several external third-party drivers available for that purpose. To
>   access ext2fs, [LTOOLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=LTOOLS&action=edit&redlink=1) (counterpart to Mtools) can sometimes be
>   used to copy data to and from ext2fs drives.

Source [FreeDOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeDOS)

---

#### CDs and USBs is what I'm really interested in

Freedos supports CR ROM drives using `xcdrom.sys`

> `XCDROM.SYS` is an UDMA and non-UDMA CD-ROM driver for DOS.
>     `XCDROM.SYS` has to be loaded in `CONFIG.SYS` / `FDCONFIG.SYS`.
>     When FreeDOS is already running, you can load `XCDROM.SYS`
>     later with `DEVLOAD`

Source [Command: xcdrom.sys](http://help.fdos.org/en/hhstndrd/base/xcdrom.htm)

There are DOS USB drivers available, for example at [DOS USB Drivers](http://bretjohnson.us/).

I've no idea whether they work with FreeDOS.

Comment: Beware that this answer deals only with hard drives: CDs or USB drives require extra drivers, and those are not 100% guaranteed to work.

Comment: CDs and USBs is what I'm really interested in (I don't need HDDs now). Can somebody tell me how to get drivers for them (CDs and USBs)?

Comment: @Vuk Answer updated.

Comment: @Vuk If this answered your question, please don't forget to [accept the answer](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking the accept button (the tick ✓ button).

Comment: Ok, I'll try it.

Comment: How exactly does this count as an answer to the OP's question? You cp/pst something marginally related from FD website, point to some drivers, and say you have no idea if it works or not?!?!

Answer (score 1):

I have FreeDOS running on metal on a DELL Latitude X1 (Centrino-powered sub laptop). If you plug in a thumb drive before you turn on the machine, it will be counted amongst the drives available and get a drive letter in FreeDOS (If it has a VFAT filesystem on it) It also shows up as a 2nd drive in fidsk.